# How to determine the size of a ParseObject.save() payload

Tags: parse-platform

I am doing some serious performance analysis against Parse.com on Android platform. I would like to know exactly the size of the request made to appname.parseapp.com for a certain ParseObject.save() operation.

Kind regards and happy Parsing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the SDKs are all just wrappers over the REST API, that means all payloads are just HTTPS traffic.

You could use any number of tools to capture that traffic and see the size of the payload. I've used [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) before (it is free), just a matter of setting your PC as the proxy for your device.